# Find rows in dataframe with the biggest difference in values in another column, R

Tags: r, dataframe, difference

I am trying to find the two first names ("First Name" column) with the biggest difference in values ("Action" column). Does anyone know how to do that? Thanks in advance!

```
data = structure(list(`First Name` = c("Till", "Roland", "Otmar", "Christoph", 
"Bianca"), Action = c(2, 1, 2, 1, 5), Reflection = c(6, 7, 6, 
7, 3), Flexibility_Thinking = c(2, 3, 3, 1, 6), Structure = c(6, 
4, 4, 7, 2)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Comment: Can you elaborate? You want to calculate difference between values in Action columns for all the pairs of First names, then select a pair of first names with the largest difference, correct?

Comment: Exactly! I want to find the names of the people who differ the most in values in column "Action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one base R approach -

```
#Get pairwise differences for all names
mat <- abs(outer(data$Action, data$Action, `-`))
#get the max difference
max_values <- apply(mat, 1, max)
#get the index where the max difference is present
max_index <- apply(mat, 1, which.max)
#Create a dataframe with first name, name of biggest difference person 
#and the difference value
result <- cbind(data[1], 
                biggest_diff = data$`First Name`[max_index], diff = max_values)

result

#  First Name biggest_diff diff
#1       Till       Bianca    3
#2     Roland       Bianca    4
#3      Otmar       Bianca    3
#4  Christoph       Bianca    4
#5     Bianca       Roland    4

#get top 2 results
head(result[order(-result$diff), ], 2)

#  First Name biggest_diff diff
#2     Roland       Bianca    4
#4  Christoph       Bianca    4
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you so much!!! Can I also do this for multiple columns at the same time so that I can see in which columns people differ the most? I updated the question to show you that the data originally has multiple columns just like "Action"

Answer (score 3):

You can use `dist` where you can choose with `method` how the distance should be calculated (`euclidean`, `maximum`, `manhattan`, `canberra`, `binary` or `minkowski`).

```
x <- as.matrix(dist(data$Action)) * lower.tri(diag(data$Action))
matrix(data$"First Name"[which(x == max(x), TRUE)], ncol=2)
#     [,1]     [,2]       
#[1,] "Bianca" "Roland"   
#[2,] "Bianca" "Christoph
```

Or for *multiple columns at the same time*.

```
x <- as.matrix(dist(data[-1])) * lower.tri(diag(data$Action))
matrix(data$"First Name"[which(x == max(x), TRUE)], ncol=2)
#[1,] "Bianca" "Christoph"
```